# sql query with 3 tables with multiple values column

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

participants (id, name)
groups (id, name)
participant_groups (participant_id, group_id)

I need to show a table with all the participants and a last column with the participant's groups, which can be several.

I have the following select that returns all the participants but if it has more than one group I have several records of the same participant.

```
SELECT *
    FROM participants
      CROSS JOIN groups
      INNER JOIN participant_groups
        ON groups.id = participant_groups.id
        AND participants.id = participant_groups.id
    ORDER BY participants.name, participants.id
```

Thanks

Comment: I fail to see the question, what is coming out, and how would you like it to look? :) - you are outputting this to php? can I see the output and how you are outputting it? as in your PHP code for handling the response.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired result [mre]

Comment: @Shlomtzion it's a simple html table with a foreach to display all the records.

Comment: If you have several same participants, why don't you try a SELECT DISTINCT(*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```sql
SELECT participants.id, participants.name, GROUP_CONCAT(groups.name) AS group_list
FROM participants
LEFT JOIN participant_groups ON participants.id = participant_groups.participant_id
INNER JOIN groups ON participant_groups.group_id = groups.id
GROUP BY participants.id
```